# Mapping an array inside an object inside an array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, array.prototype.map

I am having trouble displaying a pair of options for the corresponding prompt.

I made a .json file to hold the prompts and options.
This is the dataset:

```
    [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "hey wut r u doin",
        "options": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "Playing Pokemon",
            "nextPrompt": 2
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "Watching a movie",
            "nextPrompt": 7
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "lol you still play that??",
        "options": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "It's fun!",
            "nextPrompt": 18
          }
          {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "Just kidding ha ha...",
            "nextPrompt": 7
          }
}]
```

In the component I'm trying to go to the currentPrompt, look at the options and then from there map the text.  When I console.log(currentPrompt.options) it says undefined... Why is that?
This is my component:

```
function PromptsAndOptions() {
  const [currentPrompt, setCurrentPrompt] = useState(POA[0].text);

  return (
    <section>
      <section>{currentPrompt}</section>
      {console.log(currentPrompt)}
      <section>
        {currentPrompt.options &&
          currentPrompt.options.map(({ text }) => (
            <button key={currentPrompt.options.id}>{text}</button>
          ))}
      </section>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is `POA[0].text`? I guess you wanted `POA[0]` instead?

Comment: `POA[0].text` gives me the text of the first prompt

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON file is wrong
Try the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-08-d0fbqo?file=/src/index.jsx:175-756)

```
const POA = [
{
  id: 1,
  text: "hey wut r u doin",
  options: [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Playing Pokemon",
      nextPrompt: 2
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Watching a movie",
      nextPrompt: 7
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: 2,
  text: "lol you still play that??",
  options: [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "It's fun!",
      nextPrompt: 18
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Just kidding ha ha...",
      nextPrompt: 7
    }
  ]
}];

const [id, setId] = useState(1);
const promp = POA[id].options;

return (
<section>
  <section>{id}</section>
  {console.log(id)}
  <section>
    {promp &&
      promp.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div key={i}>Items Text Is === {item.text}</div>
            <br />
          </>
        );
      })}
    <div onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)}>
      <input type="radio" value="0" name="gender" /> First
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="gender" /> Second
    </div>
  </section>
</section>);
```

Comment: That helped a ton! Thanks!! But when I put `useState(1)` it's being put into the [ ] so it's showing the prompt at that index rather than the id. I want to be able to target the hard coded id and display that text. I can't do something like `const prompt = POA[i].id.text` but I don't know how to use two keys at the same time...